# Не отправляются данные аякс запроса в PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

Я пытаюсь отправить данные в PHP с помощью ajax запроса. Вот мой js файл

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('buy_btn');
console.log(buttons);
var titles = document.getElementsByClassName('product__title');
var descriptions = document.getElementsByClassName('product__description');
var prices = document.getElementsByClassName('product__price');
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function () {
        var title = titles[i].innerHTML;
        var description = descriptions[i].innerHTML;
        var price = prices[i].innerHTML;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/buy_product.php",
            data: { 'Title': title, 'Description': description, 'Price': price },
            success: function () {
                console.log("Success");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("Error");
            }
        })
    }
}
```

В PHP коде я хочу взять эти данные:

```
$title = $_POST['Title'];
$description = $_POST['Description'];
$price = $_POST['Price'];
```

Однако он не видит эти данные. При выводе массива POST этих данных также нет.
URL правильный, я проверял. Все данные верны. Функция success ajax запроса срабатывает. Спасибо за любую помощь

Comment: В `$.ajax` вместо `type` должно быть `method`. [Примеры для наглядности](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#entry-examples)

Comment: Исправил на method. Не помогло(

Comment: А запрос вообще отправляется? `$_POST` по прежнему пустая или нет?

Comment: Да, по прежнему пуст

Comment: Так `POST` запрос вообще отправляется или нет? Есть ошибки в консоли? Если не знаете где посмотреть `DevTools -> Network -> Fetch/XHR -> Headers -> Form Data`

Comment: И как Вы узнаете что `$_POST` пустой, если в success Вы не принимаете  ответ с сервера, нет никакого `data`, у Вас просто `console.log("Success")`

Comment: Да, в Form data у меня есть данные, которые я передаю

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131465/discussion-between-simon-and-).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать `let formData = new FormData();`  и `enctype: 'multipart/form-data'`как здесь:

```
buttons[i].onclick = function () {
    var title = titles[i].innerHTML;
    var description = descriptions[i].innerHTML;
    var price = prices[i].innerHTML;
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('Title',title);
    formData.append('Description',description);
    formData.append('Price',price );
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/buy_product.php",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        data: formData,
        success: function () {
            console.log("Success");
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("Error");
        }
    })
}
```